# How to pass Sportsipy Python sports API through Django template

Tags: python, django, api

I have been trying to work with this Python sports data api, Sportsipy. It’s pretty simple to set up and I can print the dictionaries to the terminal but when I go to pass it through my Django template it says the object is not iterable.

When I print the type() it just says the class name is sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore.Boxscores.

I have tried converting it to json and a million different things to get it to work but it just won't happen.

Im not sure how it is formatted or what the story with it is.
[screenshot of one of the endpoints in API docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wl5Z.jpg)

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from datetime import datetime
from sportsipy.ncaab.schedule import Schedule
from sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore import Boxscores


def games(request):
    """ View to return index page """

    games_today = Boxscores(datetime.today())
    print(games_today.games) <--- prints the dictionary properly

    context = {
            'games_today': games_today
        }
return render(request, 'games/games.html', context)
```

```html
    {% for game in games_today %}  
          <p class="white">{{ game.date }}</p>
          <p class="white">{{ game.home_team }}</p> 
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the documentation of the library you are using `boxscores.games` is a dictionary. You can access any key of a dictionary in template like `dictionary_object.key` (key here is treated as a literal string and) e.g. `games.date`. If you don't know the keys you can loop like `{% for key, value in dictionary_object.items %}`.

If you check Django's Documentation on  [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) you will notice you that you can perform all kinds of lookups using just the `.` operator.

As per your code `games_today = Boxscores(datetime.today())` and in the context you write `'games_today': games_today`. Now in games_today there is an **attribute** games so in your template do this:

```
{% for date, game_list in games_today.games.items %}
    Games today({{ date }}):
    {% for game in game_list %}
        <p class="white">{{ game.home_name }}</p>
        <p class="white">{{ game.away_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Why loop over `games_today.games.items`? well according to the [documentation](https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ncaab.html#sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore.Boxscores.games) `games_today.games` returns a dictionary and it contains only one key (would be multiple if `end_date` is passed) which is namely today's date in "MM-DD-YYYY" instead of figuring that date out simply looped over its `.items()`.

Comment: I have tried that. Added ‘games’ to context, passed it to html, tried games.key and I get the error that the object is not iterable. I can see all the keys because I can print the dictionary, just can’t iterate over it.

Comment: @RyanThomas what is the code you tried? Add it to your question.

Comment: Wow.. it worked! Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help. I was at this for over a week and I couldn't figure it out. I need to keep you on retainer :)

Comment: I have another similar problem with a different endpoint if you have a second to take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135298/how-to-pass-variable-from-python-api-to-django-template