# How to pass variable from Python API to Django template

Tags: python, django, api

I have been trying to work with this Python sports data api, Sportsipy. It’s pretty simple to set up and I can save data to a var and print it to the terminal but when I add it to context go to pass it through my Django template nothing shows up.

I tried calling it on the HTML side several different ways but I still haven't been able to figure it out.

[Screenshot of API endpoint doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nOkO.png)

Under the Schedule endpoint
https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ncaab.html#module-sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore

```py
    def games(request):
    """ View to return games page """

    team_schedule = Schedule('PURDUE')
    print(team_schedule)

    for game in team_schedule:
        away_total_rebounds = game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds
        print(away_total_rebounds)

    context = {
        'team_schedule': team_schedule,
        'away_total_rebounds': away_total_rebounds,
    }

    return render(request, 'games/games.html', context)
```

```html
    {% for game in team_schedule %}
         <div>
              <h4 class="white">{{ game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds }}</h4>
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `away_total_rebounds` is an integer according to the documentation (you are looping on it)? Also instead of just adding an image to the documentation give a link, it's very difficult to find the correct page in such a huge documentation.

Comment: So sorry, I added the link.

Comment: I already pointed the problem out here, `away_total_rebounds` is an integer yet you are looping on it... How would that work?

Comment: I was looping through team_schedule but it wasn’t working so I tried looping through the var

Comment: `game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds` Is that not what you want to write in the template? You are already doing this in the view, just write the similar logic in the template....

Comment: Im sorry, I am just learning and still don’t fully understand... so it would be {% for game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds in team-schedule %}?

Comment: I guess I just don’t understand why it doesn’t work when I added the logic to context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the correct answer but shouldn't your for loop have elements of the for loop? What I'm trying to say is in the template shouldn't it be like

```
{% for game in team_schedule %}
         <div>
              <h4 class="white">{{ game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds }}</h4>
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: Abdul's answer added

Comment: Change to `{{ game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds }}` and you are correct.

Comment: Still doesn't print.

Comment: Just print {{game}} and see if it's printing anything, then traverse one by one to desired item

Comment: {{ game }} doesn't print anything either.

Comment: Can you print the context before you're sending it to the other page and make sure you're passing the right context? Can you also share the results, also you can use {% debug %} in the template to get all variables that are being passed, hopefully you'll have something there

Comment: Its prints to my terminal every time I reload the webpage.

Comment: Can you post your Full Template, do you have {% block content %} and {%endblock%} wrappers around the for loop?

Comment: Yes. I am extending the base template and passing other data through just fine. away_total_rebounds is just a value within the Boxscore class that is within the Schedule class so it’s just been impossible to get to in the template.

Comment: Can you share with us what you see when it is printed on the console, at this point we don't have enough information to resolve the issue, please share the output of the console when context is printed, any or all variables in template when {%debug%} is activated (whatever is related to the context)

Comment: It just prints a list of numbers. I matched the numbers up to each game and they are correct. Also when I print team_schedule, the date and team they are playing prints.

Comment: @RyanThomas are you writing this in the correct template, i.e. `games/games.html` (and / or checking in the correct url)?

Comment: Yes. 100% positive everything is wired up properly.

Comment: Its the same exact template as the code you helped me on yesterday and that printed perfectly.

Comment: I also just made a random var and passed it through, that worked. So I think it is something in the HTML side of things, not the view.

Comment: Im not sure how much it matters but when I print type(team_schedule) it comes back "<class 'sportsipy.ncaab.schedule.Schedule'>"

Comment: Try to print out the exact value,  believe this is a simple case of nonstring convertable variables being passed to the template, try without passing everything to the template and just away_total_rebounds

Comment: I agree, I think its not converted properly. I tried just passing the away_total_rebounds into the template a long time ago and it wouldn’t print.

Comment: Maybe just print the type(var) to see the data type, you can also convert to string using str(var) to be then passed to the template, good luck

Comment: The var 'away_total_rebounds' I am passing in my context is an 'int'. 'team_schedule' just comes up as <class 'sportsipy.ncaab.schedule.Schedule'>

Comment: GOT IT!! Had to convert list(('team_schedule")) and str(game.boxscore.away_total_rebounds)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, EngineJanwaar!